# jQuery draggable function causes error in PrimeFaces JSF page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using jQuery in JSF to make a drag and drop feature. The draggable function works fine independently, but when out in a JSF page, it throws an error!

Here is the code:

```
function attachClickEvents() { 
    $(".circle").on('click', function(event){ 
        event.stopPropagation(); 
        event.stopImmediatePropagation(); 

        $(".circle").each(function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass("selected"); 
        }); 

        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
        // $(this).draggable({containment:'parent',drag: handleDragStop}); 
        $(this).draggable({containment:$(this).parent().parent().parent()}); 
    });     
}
```

What is surprising is, `$(this).addClass("selected");` piece works fine and the appearance of that marker is changed.

But the next statement throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function

I am using the JSF recommended way of including jQuery:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />
```

What's wrong?

Comment: There is nothing jsf/PrimeFaces related in the code in your question. Please make a [mcve], post version error and post the 'generic part' of the error ypu get in a search engine

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+TypeError%3A+%24(...).+is+not+a+function+jsf+primefaces+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I was explicitly adding a jquery version in my code. Also another developer who was working independently also included another version of jquery. All 3 were conflicting. I removed explicit inclusion of jquery and included the one provided by prime faces , it started working. Always make sure you dont have multiple inclusion of jquery of different versions.Hope this helps some one